# Express routing issues

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, get, routes

I'm very new to express and am running into issues getting proper routing set up. It's a homework assignment so the router file was already written, but there's a express.js file we're supposed to fill in to make calls to the api whenever a get/put/post/delete request is made at that address. The router file is set up like this:

```
var listings = require('../controllers/listings.server.controller.js'), 
    getCoordinates = require('../controllers/coordinates.server.controller.js'),
    express = require('express'), 
    router = express.Router();

/* 
  These method calls are responsible for routing requests to the correct request handler.
  Take note that it is possible for different controller functions to handle requests to the same route.
 */
router.route('/')
  .get(listings.list)
  .post(getCoordinates, listings.create);

/*
  The ':' specifies a URL parameter. 
 */
router.route('/:listingsId')
  .get(listings.read)
  .put(getCoordinates, listings.update)
  .delete(listings.delete);

/*
  The 'router.param' method allows us to specify middleware we would like to use to handle 
  requests with a parameter.

  Say we make an example request to '/listings/566372f4d11de3498e2941c9'

  The request handler will first find the specific listing using this 'listingsById' 
  middleware function by doing a lookup to ID '566372f4d11de3498e2941c9' in the Mongo database, 
  and bind this listing to the request object.

  It will then pass control to the routing function specified above, where it will either 
  get, update, or delete that specific listing (depending on the HTTP verb specified)
 */
router.param('listingId', listings.listingByID);

module.exports = router;
```

And the express.js file is like this:

```
var path = require('path'),  
    express = require('express'), 
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    config = require('./config'),
    listingsRouter = require('../routes/listings.server.routes'), 
    getCoordinates = require('../controllers/coordinates.server.controller.js');

module.exports.init = function() {
  //connect to database
  mongoose.connect(config.db.uri, {useMongoClient: true});

  //initialize app
  var app = express();

  //enable request logging for development debugging
  app.use(morgan('dev'));

  //body parsing middleware 
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  /* server wrapper around Google Maps API to get latitude + longitude coordinates from address */
  app.post('/api/coordinates', getCoordinates, function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.results);
  });

  This is the part I can't figure out:
  /* serve static files */
  app.get('/listings', listingsRouter, function(req, res){
    res.send(req.get('/'))
  });

  /* use the listings router for requests to the api */


  /* go to homepage for all routes not specified */ 

  return app;
};
```

I'm just not sure how to use the routes in the listingsRouter file with the req and res objects and I can't find any examples of a program set up like this to help. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change following

```
app.get('/listings', listingsRouter, function(req, res){
    res.send(req.get('/'))
});
```

To

```
app.use('/listings', listingsRouter);
```

[Express Router](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). Scroll down to **express.Router** section for complete info.

Hope this helpls.